# How can i remove noise in this binary image and smooth the image -openCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm doing a project on character recognition in number plate for my degree. I want to remove the noise in this binary image before skeletonizing. I'm trying to calculate the end points in this image as specified in the following paper.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3884.pdf :

I have tried erosion and dilation. But did not work. How can I remove the noises around the character'B'and smooth the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the parameters of erosion and dilation , 
like u can increase the kernel size ,
and number of iteration .
Also try morphological closing .
Hope it helps .

Share your code for more .

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It worked. I was able to skeletonize the image as well. But not fully successful. Now my next step is zoning the image and get the pixel values as shown in this paper http://www.ijcst.com/vol62/2/45-Elima-Hussain.pdf in page 227 figure 4. I'm stucked here. I could not find a good zoning method in open cv C++ . Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Its seems to be  simple algorithm , you should write yourself , atleast try and if any error then post your code .